# How to build my own Java/Python PaaS (platform-as-a-service) with Openstack?

Tags: java, python, openstack, paas, devstack

I'm running **Openstack** on a computer and want to provide a *simple* **PaaS** with it. (*it's not a big project, I'm just doing it for learning*)

I jus wanted to know the steps, the scenario, the approach, where should I start and what is the route.

I have server and client systems (nothing is **virtual**).
Host OS is **ubuntu 14.04 LTS**.

Comment: This is a really broad question.

Comment: I dont want detailed settings, jus a roadmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at Docker, Marathon and Mesos.

https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html

Basically, *just basically*:

With [Docker](https://www.docker.com/):

`Basically, you will have a Dockerfile that will configure your project`

With [Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/):

`You will deploy the Dockerfiles and scale as you want`

With [Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/):

`Mesos abstracts CPU, memory, storage, and other compute resources away from machines (physical or virtual)`

I had to do a PaaS platform and these guys helped me a lot. You should take a look. At the end, all you will need is a Dockerfile and the WAR/.egg file (and config files, if needed).

Comment: thank you very much, I'll check'em now.
is ur PaaS still on the internet?

Comment: It was a private PaaS... But if you're looking for existing (and free) PaaS to take a look too, there's this link: https://github.com/ripienaar/free-for-dev#paas

Comment: If was helpful, can you vote on the answer, please? =P

Comment: sorry I wud, but I'm just a new user...seemingly it doesnt let me vote. Says I need some reputation :-/
ASAP I get the privilege I sure will vote ;-)